# Unable to use Heroku Toolbelt [Encoding::CompatibilityError]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, encoding

I'm facing a problem for hours now. I've tried a lot of things but I can't fix it !

I'm just trying to log to Heroku via a windows console but I've always the same error message :

C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:433:in `join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1252 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:433:in`format_error'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:442:in `styled_error'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:52:in`rescue in start'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:35:in `start'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in`'

I first tried installing via 'gem install heroku' but there was a problem, I was even not able to input my password. So I found that it will work by installing with windows installer. And now I've this problem.

I've noticed that Ruby 1.9.3 was installed into the Heroku folder and that it seems to use this version instead of 2.1 that I've installed previously.

Thanks for your precious help